# I need to extract dom element of main contents in python

Tags: python, dom, web-scraping, web-crawler, extract

i'm working to extract main contents from web page without removing anything like image in python, yet most library just gives me back the text itself or cleaned dom elements.

i need dom elements themselves that contain main contents of article including image.

Is there any library for that purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean getting whole dom node with img src="" then i believe beautifulsoup4 can do that.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

but with actual image i dont know you have to make separate request for image.

Or you can use selenium https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium, It will use your browser (Firefox, Chrome) so can do anything with extracting web contents

Comment: I meant, extract not whole dom but the dom that contains only the article

Comment: for instance, "<html><body><div id = 'article'>article body here</div></body></html>" => "<div id = 'article'>article body here</div>"

Comment: yes you can do that with beautifulsoup, select appropriate node with article like [a = soup.find(id='article')] and extract contents like [a.contents]

Comment: have to automate completely for various web pages.... need to avoid doing manually